# Time Date Difference in Microseconds

Tags: python, datetime

I'm really new to Python and I have a problem with calculating the difference between two times.

I have a file with a list containing a time that a specific message left and a time that a message came back in. Each are displayed on a different line. Each are recorded in microseconds. I want to take the find the difference between the two and print the result.

Thanks so much for helping me! I really appreciate it.

Comment: can you please post some example data and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The general procedure consists in first reading the file, with something like:

```
with open('/path/to/file') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        # 'line' is the contents of each line (including line termination characters)
        # ... the strings representing the times are obtained here ...
```

Calculations with times in microseconds can then simply done with

```
int(time1_string)-int(time0_string)
```

The type conversion is important (it converts a string of characters into a number, so that mathematical operations can be performed on it).

Comment: In the list there are many in and out messages, will this differentiate between the different sets each time?

Comment: You need to add a concrete example of file lines in your question, because your question cannot be fully answered with the available information. :)